# Error: I can't find the format file pdflatex.fmt

Tags: pdftex

For no particular reason that I could identify, I was faced with the impossibility to compile any latex document and invariably got this error message each time I tried :

```
LaTeX: problems after [0] pages

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt
tcfmgr: config file `tcfmgr.map' (usually in $TEXMFMAIN/texconfig) not found.
I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'!
```

Comment: For me I simply had to copy the .fmt file into the directory the PHP file was calling it from. It worked fine from a terminal but gave the error when running via PHP.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I thought I would post this here because it gave me some cold sweats as I could not make any sense of the error message and have only two months remaining to write my thesis.

In a terminal, just type

```
sudo texconfig rehash
```

which should give

```
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN...
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVE...
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R...
mktexlsr: Done.
```

This solution was found [on this website](http://verahill.blogspot.fr/2012/04/solved-latex-bug-tcfmgr-config-file.html).

Comment: This answer led to [another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120150/is-there-a-difference-between-texconfig-rehash-and-mktexlsr/120164). It is easier and more conventional to simply use `sudo texhash`.

Comment: Both rehash and texhash produce an analogous output, but I am still returned the same errore message.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and none of the sites I visited helped.  This is for linux.  I was installing on a semi-incomplete backed-up image of a previous computer.  My problem turned out to be the pre-existing config files in /etc/texmf/updmap.d

This is what I did:

1. Remove all tex packages:
   sudo apt-get remove texlive*
2. PURGE all tex packages:
   sudo apt-get purge texlive*
3. Delete everything in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
4. Re-install desired tex packages:
   sudo apt-get install texlive etc

It now seems to work fine.

Phil

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the file is in your `TeX` search path.

```
kpsewhich pdflatex.ini
```

If the result is empty, then add path to `TEXINPUTS`, e.g. put into .bash_profile

```
export TEXINPUTS=.:/opt/tex/cur/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/
```

UPD. If this doesn't help with other paths, it means that your installation is corrupt. To reisntall would be better in that case (I'm doing that at the moment).

Comment: Nuking and re-installing a 5GB piece of software, that took over 120 minutes of full tilt CPU, is a bit of an upsell for such a weak kind of error, I think the better solution as this point is to `> /dev/null` this `pdflatex` kaynine excrement.  Problem solved!

Comment: This is it. On my system the `pdflatex.ini` was missing. So e.g. on Archlinux: `pacman -F pdflatex.ini` to find that the package to provide the file is `texlive-latex` and then install it.

Answer (score 1):

If this can be of any help it happened the same to me and I realized that, since the last time I had opened Texmaker, I had installed Anaconda. It turns out that Anaconda had installed a texlive-core package, which was conflicting with my original texlive installation.
I just had to remove the anaconda package through:

```
conda remove texlive-core
```

and it worked. None of the previous solutions worked for me for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem in openSUSE Tumbleweed with re-installing texlive via

```
 zypper remove texlive*
 zypper install texlive
```

Comment: This doesn't work if recommended packages are not set to be installed as well.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue for me

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install texlive
```

Answer (score 0):

On Arch Linux, I fixed the issue by installing all of `texlive-*` packages:

```
pacman -Ssq texlive-* | sudo pacman -S -
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to install:

```bash
sudo pacman -S extra/texlive-latex extra/texlive-latexextra extra/texlive-plaingeneric
```

For exporting org-mode files as PDF.