# Is there a difference between texconfig rehash and mktexlsr?

Tags: packages, installing, texlive

With reference to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64894/error-i-cant-find-the-format-file-pdflatex-fmt/64895#64895);
Is there a difference between texconfig hash and mktexlsr?

For example: Is `sudo texconfig rehash` able to clean up ls-R 
in cases where `mktexlsr` remains deficient? or;
Is this only due to the `sudo` in the former command?

Comment: The recommended call for recent versions of TeX Live is `texhash` or `mktexlsr` (that are exactly the same).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading the man pages and running a few straightforward tests, I found out this:

- `texconfig rehash` calls `mktexlsr`, yet a `[directories]` argument is not passed on.
- `mktexlsr` accepts a `[directories]` argument.
- `texhash` calls `mktexlsr` and passes on a `[directories]` argument. `texhash` as a command name is easier to remember than "make TeX ls-R", though.

A number of system folders are skipped because of being write-protected to normal users. So, it is better to use `sudo texhash` if you can, [except when (re)hashing `texhash ~/texmf`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32167/texlive-wont-find-files-in-home-texmf/130082#130082).

Comment: I have put a cross-link comment at [the page that led to this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64894/error-i-cant-find-the-format-file-pdflatex-fmt/64895#64895).