# LaTeX make4ht freeze

Tags: make4ht

I use make4ht to generate html file with css from latex document. And when I manually execute this command

```
make4ht main-tex -c tex4ht.cfg
```

it compiles part of LaTeX, then freeze with new line and "?" mark waiting for any key pressed, then it compiles next part and few times situation repeats. After that I have fully generated html file. That was a easy part, now if I want to use ie. Jenkins to do that, make4ht generates only first part of html, and skip everything that would be generated after freeze. 
Does anyone know why it behave in such way, and how to force it to build everything without key pressing?

MWE (copied from [LaTeX Error: \theHchapter undefined when using tex4ht with hyperref and appendix package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140008/latex-error-thehchapter-undefined-when-using-tex4ht-with-hyperref-and-appendix))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\author{me}
\title{title}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{first}
  some text

\section{two}
  some text in section 2

\begin{appendices}
\section{somesection inside appendices}
  some text again
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of a LaTeX document where this behavior still occurs and whatever error messages make4ht gives (if any)?

Comment: ok, preparing such minimal document will take some time, and the only error I found is

    ! LaTeX Error: Command \theHchapter undefined.

    See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
    Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
     ...

    l.1 \begin{appendices}

    ?

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Does this concern also exist when compiling with LaTeX? If yes, there might be some errors in your code.

Comment: ok I found something, and looks like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140008/latex-error-thehchapter-undefined-when-using-tex4ht-with-hyperref-and-appendix is ananswer to my question.

Comment: @darvark please still update your question with a sample coe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reuse the `appendix.4ht` file I posted earlier:

```
\def\@blockelement#1{% for handling paragraphs in block level elements
    \ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{#1}
}
\renewcommand{\@chap@pppage}{%
    \chapter*{\appendixpagename}
}

\renewcommand{\@sec@pppage}{%
    \section*{\appendixpagename}
    \nobreak
    \@afterheading
}

\ConfigureEnv{appendices}{\@blockelement{<div class="appendices">}}{\@blockelement{</div>}}{}{}
\ifdefined\theHchapter\else\newcommand\theHchapter{\Alph{chapter}}\fi
\ifdefined\theHsection\else\newcommand\theHsection{\Alph{section}}\fi
```

I've also added this to the `tex4ht` sources,  so the support for the `appendix` package should be added to the TeX distributions soon.

This is the generated page:

[image]