# Can't Compile with pdflatex After Installing texlive on an Arch Based Linux Distro

Tags: pdftex, texlive, linux

I installed LaTex on my computer that runs Parabola which is very similiar to Arch, by the following command:
`sudo pacman -S texlive-most`.
During the installation I remember that this error appeared on the screen:
`error: command failed to execute correctly`.
To check that LaTex works I created the file test.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    dfvlkmdfv
\end{document}
```

I typed `pdflatex test.tex`, but that didn't work well. The result was:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Parabola GNU/Linux-libre) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
mktexfmt:   /home/michael/.texlive/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt [INFO]: writing formats under /home/michael/.texlive/texmf-var/web2c
mktexfmt [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=pdflatex, skipped
mktexfmt [INFO]: Total formats: 0
mktexfmt [INFO]: exiting with status 0
I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'!
```

I tried to do `sudo texconfig rehash`, as advised here: [Error: I can't find the format file pdflatex.fmt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64894/error-i-cant-find-the-format-file-pdflatex-fmt)
but it didn't work, I got:
`/usr/bin/texconfig: line 1304: mktexlsr: command not found`.
So do you have any suggestions?

Comment: is `/home/michael/.texlive/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf` new or is it an old config from a previous installation hanging around and messing things up? if you are installing it system wide with sudo I wouldn't expect it to be using ~michael/.texlive at all

Comment: I don't have ```/home/michael/.texlive/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf```. In ```/home/michael/.texlive```, I have only one directory named ```texmf-var``` and inside it there's another directory named ```web2c``` which is empty. This installation is entirely new, I didn't installed LaTex on this new Parabola install before.

Comment: I can't help a lot: I haven't used a linux-packaged texlive for some years, with the upstream texlive from tug fmtutil.cnf would be here /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/fmtutil.cnf  in a system wide installation (with most things under /usr/local/texlive/2020)

Comment: I don't have this  ```/usr/local/texlive``` directory. Is that normal?

Comment: yes linux packaged texlive usually ends up in /usr/bin and /usr/lib etc, but an upstream texlive installs in /usr/local/texlive always (then you have to add it to the PATH by hand) but the basic layout below the installation root is usually the same so for me article.cls is `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Honestly I don't really understand how texlive works and everything you are saying, I just want it to work. So yeah, if you or someone else have any suggestions on what I should do that would really help me.

Comment: I haven't used arch-packaged texlive for some time (vanilla is easier) but have you checked that texlive-most should actually contain the file mktexlsr? Maybe check which package does.